# I can't manage to move files properly in Python

Tags: python

So I made this script in to sort my desktop files into folders:

```
# Desktop Organization Script

import os
import shutil

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
src = userhome + '/Desktop/'
dst = src+ 'org/'

f_exe = [".exe",".lnk"]
f_web = [".php",".html",".css"]
f_images = [".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".ico",".gif",".JPG"]
f_video = [".avi"]
f_music  = [".ogg",".wav",".mp3"]
f_document = [".txt",".pdf",".ppt",".pptx",".docx",".doc",".xls"]
f_multimedia = [".max",".m",".ase",".swf",".fla"]
f_zip = [".rar",".zip",".7z"]
f_book = [".epub"]
f_other = [".s2z",".url"]

formats = [f_exe,f_web,f_images,f_music,f_document,f_multimedia,f_zip,f_book,f_other,f_video]

def main(): 
    txtlist = os.listdir(src);
    for file in txtlist:
        sortFiles(file)

def sortFiles(file):        
    for group in formats:
        for format in group:
            if file.endswith(format):
                    if format in f_exe: directory = "Executables"
                    if format in f_web: directory = "Web Development"
                    if format in f_images: directory = "Images"
                    if format in f_music: directory = "Music"
                    if format in f_document: directory = "Documents"
                    if format in f_multimedia: directory = "Multimedia"
                    if format in f_zip: directory = "RARs and ZIPs"
                    if format in f_book: directory = "Books"
                    if format in f_other: directory = "Others"
                    if format in f_video: directory = "Videos"
                    if not os.path.exists(dst+directory+"/"):
                        os.makedirs(dst+directory+"/")
                    shutil.move(src+file,dst+directory+"/") 


main()
```

Although this does work with most files, sometimes there are files that won't be moved by this script, even if they share extension with files that did move properly. Actually, I am only having problems when moving shortcuts (.lnk extension). Some of them move, some of them do not move. The ones that don't move aren't even returned by the os.listdir() command. Any ideas?

Comment: permissions problems?

Comment: you can use some logging mechanisms to see which one and dive into the ones that are not moved?

Comment: I just saw that many files didn't move because there was already a file with the same name in the destination folder. However, I still have problems when I want to move shorcuts (.lnk extension), some do move but some don not.

Comment: Are there any patterns to it? Are the extensions in a case other than lower?  Do you have the files open?  Are you getting any errors?  Try adding a print statement to see if what you think is trying to move is actually trying.

Comment: Hoang Pham, I don't really know what kind of logging mechanisms do you mean.

Comment: @woot there is no pattern whatsoever. However, I printed what the os.listdir command returns and the files that were not moved aren't even being printed.

Comment: And it isn't a case-sensitive thing?  like using file.lower().endswith(format.lower())

Comment: @woot the thing is, os.listdir doesn't even return this files so there is no file in which to apply the .endswith() command.

Comment: as a total aside, if you write f = {} and then f['exe'] = {'ext': ['.exe', '.lnk'], 'directory': 'Executables'} and so on you should be able to compress your code significantly.

Answer (score 0):

As some *.lnk files are not listed by os.listdir(), I assume that they are not available in the user's desktop directory.

The reason for that might be that those files are stored in the "public desktop", i.e. **c:\Users\Public\Desktop**, and shared across all users.
Since you are only targeting the current user (userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')), the public Deskop remains "hidden" to your code.